# v8: How to include a Script inside FunctionTemplate

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I'm doing this to have a MongoDB nodejs driver wrapper using nodejs add ons. 
I want to create a wrapper to remove the asynchronous nature. Sadly, the said driver doesn't have 'sync' option.

I tried building the mongodb c driver and mongodb c++ driver but had [no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017221/understanding-native-libraries-mongo-c-driver-libbson).

Here's my question:
How can I parse a stringed javascript function body to v8 function?

I have this code

```
//args[0] is from the parameter: const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args

Local<ObjectTemplate> global_templ = ObjectTemplate::New();
global_templ->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "db"), args[0]);
Local<Context> context = Context::New(isolate, NULL, global_templ);

string str1 = "";
str1 += "if(!(db.serverConfig.isConnected && db.serverConfig.isConnected())) ";
str1 += "   return false;";
str1 += "else";
str1 += "   return true;";
const char * str2 = str1.c_str();
context->Enter();
Local<String> source = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, str2);

Local<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);

Local<Value> result = script->Run();
args.GetReturnValue().Set(result);
context->Exit();
```

this will produce an error : Illegal return statement
I concluded I have to put this function.

```
Local<FunctionTemplate> func = FunctionTemplate::New(isolate);
```

I don't know how to parse the function body into the template. :'(

PS: I'm a newb so please make the words newb friendly. lol. haha

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to remove Node's asynchronous nature? Why don't you embrace it and use a callback? If you don't want async, go back to PHP :)

Comment: AFAIK, Javascript's asynchronous nature was intended for the front end. to make requests and still handle views without looking as if its waiting for a data. Now javascripts being used for backend, reading files, accesing db. Even node has sync options on some of their modules.

Comment: Async is the main power of JS. It's useful on the front-end, so how could this be a handicap on the back-end? Everyone codes all their Node apps asynchronously, we all use this power instead of destroying it or working around it. We make async database calls, async routing, async everything, and it's awesome. There's something in your reasoning that I really don't get. As I said, if you're not ready for async, use an old, slow and synchronous language like PHP. No offense but I mean it.

Comment: @JeremyThille The javascript language has very little to do with synchronous/asynchronous and none of its power comes from that.   Maybe you're thinking about certain APIs?  But there's nothing about them that is really javascript specific.

Comment: @JeremyThille if you dont understand a hint of my reasoning, you're not trying to understand. I won't be sticking with callback hell and too much typing with promises(when every action needs previous action be done, you'll understand). Don't get me wrong, javascript overall is amazing, but its not only me who's trying to find a way towards cleaner synchronous code. See ES6 Generators. PHP isn't old and slow. If you still dont get it, you're the one who's old and slow. No offense but I mean it. :)

Comment: Yes you're probably right, apologies. It's just, whenever someone tries to go against JS's async nature, it's, well, going against nature. It's like saying, "I want to use JS, but without its speed and its awesome features". But if you do, you certainly have your reasons, even if I don't understand them. And yes, PHP **is** much slower because it's sync (so it halts and waits) and JS is faster because it's async (it carries on and doesn't wait). Only beginners / bad coders end up with a callback hell, if that's what you fear. Long story short, I don't have an answer to your question ;)

Comment: @JeremyThille javascript has no asynchronous nature.  Have you read the language specifications?  Why do you keep saying this?

Comment: @xaxxon javascript is asynchronous by default because of its non blocking single threaded nature. If you wont answer the question, please do not comment anymore.

Comment: @RichardDomingo "non blocking single threaded nature. " where do you get that from?   Virtually everything in javascript is blocking.  Other than settimeout, I believe everything in javascript is blocking.  Here's the specification if you wnat to double check for yourself:  https://tc39.github.io/ecma402/